# How can I open a dapp in mist (v0.7.1)?

Tags: mist, dapps

I can't find a way to open a dapp/enter url in Mist browser (v0.7.1). Do I need to download any special build, build it from master, or is there a switch for this?

Answer (score 5):

The Mist that is released publically does not contain the full browser functionality, only the Wallet App. In order to access the true Mist browser, you can use the really old [prebuilt teaser release](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.3.6), or you can build from source, and change the `global.mode` flag in `main.js` to `"mist"`.

See the [README](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/master/README.md) for instructions

Comment: For more info see: What is the relationship between Mist and Ethereum Wallet?  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2690/42