# Where can I go if I still have problems with syncing the blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I've searched online, this [Stack](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly) [Exchange,](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/how-can-i-empty-the-blockchain-to-allow-for-fast-sync) including [synchronization](/questions/tagged/synchronization), and am still having problems with syncing Geth.  Where else can I look and try to get help?

Comment: At the risk of suggesting trivial stuff, when I have syncing issues (everything else seems fine, but `geth` just won't load blocks) as ofthen as not I can either: a) Make sure my system clock is properly set. Even a few seconds off of "net" time will prevent syncing, or b) Manually use `admin.addPeer(<known_good_peer_enode_addr>)` to add known network network peer.

By now my clock is almost always spot-on, but the second method (especially on our corporate test net) almost always helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Geth:

- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues
- https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum

For the [Ethereum Wallet or Mist:](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2690/42)

- https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues
- https://gitter.im/ethereum/mist

The issues list can help determine if your problem is a known bug and how others have dealt with it.

Gitter is the live chat with the community and includes the core developers. (You do not need to install any software to use Gitter since it works with the browser.)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue for a week now and the only solution that has worked for me is to shutdown (ctrl-C) and restart (geth.exe)  the sync itself in command prompt.

If anyone could provide a great way to automate a sync restart once the cmnd prompt window displays :

> Synchronisation failed: no peers to keep download active

That'd be super swell. Something in Powershell to automate a shutdown restart.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Ok, noted. It was sort of an answer then an idea for automation.