# Blockchain sync... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

Okay,

I know this has been asked a thousand times (i know this because I've seen all the post/threads) but I have to ask again in hopes something has changed.

I am trying to run a node and no matter what I do it never seems to sync. Its made it to block #1.6M after TWO DAYS but my computer crashed.

This last run I used (after clearing my db):

```
geth --fast --cache=1024
```

It took almost two days for it to get to block # 1.6M and then my machine locked up. After a reboot I saw it started back on block 0 and is very slow.

I made a copy of my chaindata before booting up geth in case it cleared out for some reason.

What can I do to increase this sync time?!

Comment: Also http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/where-can-i-go-if-i-still-have-problems-with-syncing-the-blockchain

Answer (score 1):

Two main reasons for a slow blockchain download:

- Make sure that the port UDP/TCP 30303 is open on your rooter and enough peers are connected.
- Make sure, that your firewall doesn't block the connection.