# Syncing filled all my space, where is the data and how do I remove everything as clean as possible?

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu, linux

I'm running geth on a distant linux Ubuntu machine, I have a total of 12Gb disk space, I thought that would be enough, but it wasn't. I only had the minimal LAMP settings, I installed Geth with [these instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu), (I didn't check then but I'm not sure it took that much space). I started syncing and tried installing solC at the same time, and I reached size limit.

This is more of an open question because I can't seem to find convincing answer about WHERE the files are located when I run `geth console` or `geth --testnet console`. The `chaindata` folders are way too small, the whole `.ethereum` directory is only 2.1Gb. What is the difference between `.ethereum/chaindata` and `.ethereum/geth/chaindata` ?

Bottomline is is there plan of the geth file architecture for linux ? It seems to be everywhere and I have no idea how to delete everything. I'd also like to know why `/usr/` got filled 5 Gb while all the blockchain data is in `/<username>/.ethereum`.

Answer (score 3):

12 GB is pretty tight for a full Ubuntu installation. And this issue is not fully related to Ethereum in first place. Let's answer this bottom-up:

> I'd also like to know why `/usr/` got filled 5 Gb while all the blockchain data is in `~/.ethereum`.

`/usr` is where all your linux applications are installed to. Most likely `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` contains all binaries for your Ubuntu installation. 5GB is actually pretty small for a whole `/usr` directory. I just checked mine on ArchLinux and it's 6.4GB:

```
 $ du -sh /usr
6.4G    /usr
```

So, this has nothing to do with Ethereum in first place.

To cleanly remove all Ethereum data, all you need to do is

1. **Backup your keys in `~/.ethereum/keystore/` or `~/.parity/keys/`**.
2. Remove everything in `~/.ethereum/` or `~/.parity/`.

There is not much more to it.

And because you asked about the confusing directory structure: geth recently integrated a [Swarm](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/375/87) node and therefore the `chaindata/` got moved from `~/.ethereum/` to `~/.ethereum/geth/`. After launching and attaching a Swarm node, you will see there is a `~/.ethereum/swarm/` directory, too. That's pretty much it.

Whith one exception: If you have the [Ethereum Wallet or Mist Browser](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2690/87) installed, there are additional user data stored in `~/.config/Ethereum\ Wallet/` or `~/.config/Mist/` respectively. This contains logs and sometimes node binaries for geth (and/or eth).