# What is a geth account and how does it relate with ethereum wallets?

Tags: go-ethereum

I've created an account within geth, where I've entered a password and been given an address. However, I've also created an Ethereum wallet within JAXX. How would I be able to import the JAXX wallet to geth, or have the two wallets communicate, if they are indeed both wallets? That said, once I begin mining, how will the mined ether enter the wallet such that I can transact with it?

Answer (score 2):

An Ethereum wallet can store ether and tokens. Ethereum is the underlying system and can be accessed with wallet software like Jaxx and `geth`, just like how e-mail can be accessed with Mail.app, Outlook, and Thunderbird.

However, unlike traditional e-mail, the individual Ethereum wallet software can create addresses. In that way, it's a bit more like creating an account on Yahoo! mail or Hotmail. And, just like how it's possible to access Yahoo! mail from Hotmail or another mail client, it is possible to access the wallets you create with Jaxx and `geth` in other Ethereum wallets. You can search for terms like `Jaxx import geth` to find out how to get your wallet from one program to another. You'll end up with a bunch of links which you'll have to figure out which you can trust the information contained in. Understanding a bit about how the wallet software can be burdensome, but will potentially save you from a huge amount of stress later. The instructions for going from Jaxx to `geth` here look legitimate/don't seem malicious: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4jnjwd/importing_jaxx_wallet_to_mist/ . Mist is a graphical frontend that can be used with `geth`.

An alternative to importing/exporting keys is to do the equivalent of forwarding your mail between e-mail accounts manually: you can send ether from one to another (paying transaction fees in the process).

Regarding mining, it depends if you are solo mining or pool mining. If you are solo mining, you set your etherbase in your mining software to your wallet address and, whenever you find a block, the power of the blockchain will compel your wallet to increase its balance. If you're using a pool, you can usually (?) set a payout address to receive payments for your contribution to the mining process for the pool. The pool will periodically send payments to the account you list and that's all there is to that. For the pool, the transaction is no different from paying for a cup of coffee using the blockchain. Just a simple transfer of ether.

Comment: Thank you for the further information. I've looked at the [Mist releases page](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/v0.8.10) and I see that there are in fact two items: "Ethereum Wallet" and "Mist". What is the difference between these two things?


Also, you mentioned solomining and pool mining. I understand what both are, fundamentally, but how could I learn more about actually involving myself within them? Rather, what are the suggested utilities to get into either of them?

Comment: To answer the first question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/what-is-the-relationship-between-mist-and-ethereum-wallet . I don't understand your second question; could you rephrase that, please?

Comment: Sorry, what programs would you recommend for ether mining, for both solo and pool mining? I understand the concepts of how they work, just don't know the places to start.